# How to boost my application security?

Tags: symfony, security

I have an application with the framework Symfony, I have users with particular rights, if they don't have the right to access into a page, I must block them, but the users still can access into page with modifying URLs. For example I have this URL that they have the right to access in it:

```
 dialog/campany/sms/fid/setting/new
```

and they don't have the right to access to this URL:

```
dialog/campany/mail/fid/setting/new
```

but they can by remplacing `sms` by `mail`.

Comment: What did you try? Also your question lacks any detail about your configuration and code.

Comment: The standard way of denying access is to check the user's credentials for every access and redirect to a failure page if they do not have the right credentials. How have you blocked them presently?

Answer (score 0):

You have to checkout how your security.yml is configured and control the access from there. If you need information about it you can visit: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html.

Also you could control the access making a function that checks the user's credentials before given access to a given page.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that `ROLE_SMS` can only access to `dialog/campany/sms/` and `ROLE_MAIL` can only access to `dialog/campany/mail/`

In app/config/security.yml , you should have:

```
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/dialog/campany/sms/, roles: ROLE_SMS }
        - { path: ^/dialog/campany/mail/, roles: ROLE_MAIL }
```

If you only want to limit the /new URL, you can change the path to:

```
        - { path: ^/dialog/campany/sms/fid/setting/new$, roles: ROLE_SMS }
        - { path: ^/dialog/campany/mail/fid/setting/new$, roles: ROLE_MAIL }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this roles must be defined somewhere , where i define them ?

Comment: You define your roles in `security.yml` . If you are using FOSUserBundle, check their documentation, for how to affect roles, if not, you can find basic config here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html